# STRING_SPLIT : Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'

Tags: sql, split, sql-server-2017

I am using the STRING_SPLIT function to split a string based on a delimiter in SQL 2017 (compatibility level = 120). When I ran the following query, it's giving me the desired results

```
select email, value from <database.schema.table>
cross apply STRING_SPLIT(<column>,';')
where trim(value) not in ('string1','string2');
```

However, if I use the same query in a SQL procedure within the same database it doesn't work? I understand that it could be a compatibility issue but I am confused why the select one runs then?

Comment: Under which database is the standalone query executing? Given you have 3-part naming, I suspect it's a different DB. The compatibility level needs to be 130, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#compatibility-level-130